# How long to boil curry sauce left sealed in fridge three weeks to make safe

Tags: food-safety

Please this is not a duplicate: This is not a general question about food storage time and safety, about warming stored food but about boiling food that is possibly spoiled. Or even let's say spoiled.

I am not talking about simply reheating but about raising the temperature to at least boiling and keeping it there for at least an hour.

I didn't bother freezing it because I was planning on returning home after the weekend. But things turned out to keep me away for three weeks.

It's a tomato sauce based curry with some ground meat. I'm thinking to add a bit of water bring it to a boil and let it simmer for the afternoon.

Safe?

Comment: Welcome to the site! It is a duplicate, please read the link as it has everything you need to know, which is throw it away for your own good.

Answer (score 2):

You might get lucky and not get sick if you eat it, but it would be risky to eat it at this point.
Boiling won't fix the kind of spoilage that happens with tomatoes and meat over time.